# How to dump .NET JIT-ed generic method with windbg?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, windbg

I need to inspect code, that JIT emits for generic method with different struct parameters. I read articles about WinDbg and [SOS.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension) and it's possible to inspect non-generic methods. But for generic methods, which should be JIT-ed for each struct type there is no JIT-ed code in method table, where can i find it?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Foo<T>(T arg)
        {
            //some code here
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.Foo("test");
            program.Foo(1.0);
            program.Foo(new Guid());
            program.Foo((byte)1);
            program.Foo((char)1);
            program.Foo(1);
        }
    }
}
```

WinDbg:

```
0:006> .loadby sos clr
0:006> !Name2EE ConsoleApp1!ConsoleApp1.Program
Module:      00007ffa3abf4118
Assembly:    ConsoleApp1.exe
Token:       0000000002000002
MethodTable: 00007ffa3abf5a18
EEClass:     00007ffa3abf24b8
Name:        ConsoleApp1.Program
```

Dump method table

```
0:006> !DumpMT -md 00007ffa3abf5a18
    EEClass:         00007ffa3abf24b8
    Module:          00007ffa3abf4118
    Name:            ConsoleApp1.Program
    mdToken:         0000000002000002
    File:            D:\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\net462\ConsoleApp1.exe
    BaseSize:        0x18
    ComponentSize:   0x0
    Slots in VTable: 7
    Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 0
    --------------------------------------
    MethodDesc Table
               Entry       MethodDesc    JIT Name
    00007ffa9759c080 00007ffa970f7fb8 PreJIT System.Object.ToString()
    00007ffa97604360 00007ffa970f7fc0 PreJIT System.Object.Equals(System.Object)
    00007ffa97674770 00007ffa970f7fe8 PreJIT System.Object.GetHashCode()
    00007ffa975cf570 00007ffa970f8000 PreJIT System.Object.Finalize()
    00007ffa3ad005c0 00007ffa3abf5a10    JIT ConsoleApp1.Program..ctor()
    00007ffa3ad00078 00007ffa3abf59e0   NONE ConsoleApp1.Program.Foo(!!0) // "base" IL code
    00007ffa3ad00480 00007ffa3abf5a00    JIT ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

And ofc I got no code for Foo

```
0:006> !U 00007ffa3abf59e0
Not jitted yet
```

Is it any ideas?

Comment: See if [this page](https://alexandrnikitin.github.io/blog/dotnet-generics-under-the-hood/) helps you out. (I'm too lazy to try it myself and cook up an answer.)

Comment: If you just want to inspect the IL outcomes for various C#, head over to https://sharplab.io; I entered your code there and it does indeed show the IL for `Foo`

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I already saw it, nothing that can help me

Comment: @sellotape, cool project! But I don't need IL code, because IL code of generic-method is type-independent and I need JIT-ed code. But I got the desired result with attribute [SharpLab.Runtime.JitGeneric(typeof(int))] and selecting JIT asm, thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant, no, i'm sure that code is jited at this time. The problem is that jited generic methods stored not in this table, MT has only IL code common for all types, "open generic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code and compiled it as x86 debug build. I then attached to the process and waited until it terminated.

I find the same result as you:

```
   Entry MethodDe    JIT Name
[...]
00250038 00204d34   NONE JitExample2.Program.Foo(!!0)
```

Here it says `NONE`, which has the meaning "not jitted".

```
0:000> !dumpmd  00204d34  
Method Name:  JitExample2.Program.Foo(!!0)
[...]
IsJitted:     no
```

So the answer seems to be confirmed: it's not jitted.

I don't know any official method of getting a list of jitted generic methods. But with the help of `!bpmd` it's possible:

```
0:000> !bpmd JitExample2 JitExample2.Program.Foo
Found 1 methods in module 00204024...
MethodDesc = 00204d34
Setting breakpoint: bp 0025074A [JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.Char, mscorlib]](Char)]
Setting breakpoint: bp 002506EA [JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.Byte, mscorlib]](Byte)]
Setting breakpoint: bp 00250687 [JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.Guid, mscorlib]](System.Guid)]
Setting breakpoint: bp 00250627 [JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.Double, mscorlib]](Double)]
Setting breakpoint: bp 002505B0 [JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.__Canon)]
Setting breakpoint: bp 002507AA [JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.Int32, mscorlib]](Int32)]
```

You can then use the addresses after `bp` to show the JIT code:

```
0:000> !u 0025074A 
Normal JIT generated code
JitExample2.Program.Foo[[System.Char, mscorlib]](Char)
Begin 00250728, size 4b

C:\Users\For example John\JitExample2\Program.cs @ 8:
00250728 55              push    ebp
00250729 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
0025072b 83ec10          sub     esp,10h
0025072e 33c0            xor     eax,eax
[...]
```